# UIColor colorWithPatternImage

Tags: objective-c

The documentation for the method colorWithPatternImage of the UIColor class states:

**During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.**

This means that if the object's frame is larger than the size of my image used with the method colorWithPatternImage, then the image is tiled to fit. However, I would like for it to be stretched instead. Is this possible? How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UIColor with **colorWithPatternImage** will not let your UIImage stretched
If you want to use **stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:** try UIViewImage